# Phonegap multiple file download with progress bar

Tags: cordova, download

Following code downloads multiple files, but progress bar isn't updating. It does update if I remove loop and download one file only. Even progress bar was working before for multiple files, but dont know hwat I have done wrong now. I have also tried to put var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer(); outside loop

```
for(i=0;i<lesson_audio.length;i++){
        var fileTransfer = new FileTransfer();
        var filePath = fs_path+"/"+lesson_audio[i];

        var uri = encodeURI("http://myurl/"+lesson_audio[i]);

                fileTransfer.onprogress = function(progressEvent) {
                    perc = Math.floor((progressEvent.loaded / progressEvent.total) * 100);
                    $('#progress-bar').val(perc); 
                    $('#progress-bar').slider('refresh');
                }
                fileTransfer.download(
                    uri,
                    filePath,
                    function(entry) {
                       $("#progress-text").html($("#progress-text").html() + "download complete:" + entry.fullPath + "\n");
                    },
                    function(error) {
                        $("#progress-text").html($("#progress-text").html() + "download error:" + error.source + "\n")

                    }
                );

    }
```

Comment: So you didn't make any changes, it just stopped working? Did you update any files anywhere? Do you see any logs or error messages anywhere or anything? Does the progress bar work partially (like for the first file, then nothing) or it just doesn't work at all?

Comment: I did try to put progress code inside/outside the loop. Also inserted #progress-text update line etc. My file path is correct.

Answer (score 0):

Have you considdered in downloading a file which hold all files you wanna donwload? Like a file-map. You're downloading one file, read it out and then putting all entries (files you wanna download) in an array. 
So then you have an array of file-entry you wanna download and every time you've downloaded a file (using pop) the array is shrinking. You can then show the progress of the actual file and the total progress of all files to download coz you know the length of the filemap-Array at the beginning and removing every succeeded download an entry.

Simon McDonalds one wrote a pretty nice gist [Here](https://gist.github.com/macdonst/3835045)